# CAML Query for two reference fields that point to the same SharepointID

Tags: caml-query

I've got a SP2007 list (List A) with two reference-fiels (Column 1; Column 2) that reference items from a different list (List B). For some Opalis automation I need a CAML Query that gives me the results of where Column 1 = Column 2.

Any Ideas?

Comment: didn't you succeed by setting the query to `<Eq><FieldRef name='column1' /><FieldRef name='column2' /></Eq>` ?

Comment: yeah, but that doesn't work :/ 
Detail: Exception occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020009 (DISP_E_EXCEPTION))0x80020009

Comment: and what about `<Eq><FieldRef name='column1' LookupId="TRUE" /><Value type='Integer'><FieldRef name='column2'  LookupId="TRUE" /></Value></Eq>` ?

Comment: U2U CAML Query Builder throws an error "One of more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.0x81020014". Same message when I change the type of column1 to "Lookup". Opalis just ignores the CAML and returns all rows :|

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using a Lookup choice field. You'll need a query to run against List A like:

```
<Where>
   <And>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="ColumnOne" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer">3</Value></Eq>
      <Eq><FieldRef Name="ColumnTwo" LookupId="TRUE" /><Value Type="Integer">3</Value></Eq>
   </And>
</Where>
```

Where the integer value of `3` is the ID of the choice in List B.

If you don't know the ID of the choice in list B, you'll have to look it up manually or with another query.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but it doesn't quite work for this problem. ColumnOne and ColumnTwo from List B are Lookup fields to List A. And I need the items from List B where ColumnOne is the same value as Column B.
Can I somehow query the value of ColumnTwo and pass that value as a replacement for the Value _3_ in the ColumnOne within one CAML Query?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to have two queries. One to find the value of ColumnTwo, then one to find where ColumnOne and ColmumnTwo both equal that value.